# Ceiling Fan Bracing

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm looking to add a ceiling fan to an existing junction box. The current junction box runs parallel to a joist (which it's screwed into on one end) and is circular on the other end. Which of the two options would be better:
- Add a 2x6 for bracing on the top of the junction box between the joists where attached (would nailing or screwing it be better?)
- Remove the current box, and put in a fan rated metal box. This would require me to cut and patch drywall, since the current box has an odd shape.

Any insights on what's the best / easiest option are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing box?

Comment: Here's the current box: https://www.amazon.com/Madison-Electric-Products-MSBFAN-Adjustable/dp/B00H8NV1SM

Answer (score 1):

### Try a beefier box

If you want a side-joist mounted box, the [Hubbell/Raco 294](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-4-in-Round-Ceiling-Fan-Support-Box-For-Old-and-New-Work-2-1-8-in-Deep-with-1-2-in-KO-s-294/203743168) is rated for 70lbs fan support, as per [this brochure](https://hubbellcdn.com/brochure/RA-380.pdf).  Note that it is a new-work box, so it may require a bit of drywall work to install.

The reason your existing box is inadequate is because a fan-rated box's fan load rating not only considers the weight of the fan, but the *dynamic loads* placed on the box by the big spinning thingy attached to it, and your fan clearly imparts too much loading to the box for a 50lb rated box to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck, that is a fan rated box.  If it's installed per the manufacturer's instructions with three large screws into the face of the joist, it's rated for a fan up to 50 pounds according to the [manufacturer's specifications](http://meproducts.net/index.php/download_file/-/view/93).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the fans installation guide says up to 70 lbs is required, in spite of the fan weighing less than that.